# Segmentation fault when writting full location of the file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Quick question
This code gives me Segmentation fault error

```
f = fopen("~/proj/viagens.txt", "r");
```

But this one doesnt

```
f = fopen("viagens.txt", "r");
```

Why's that?

Comment: Does `fopen` lead to a segmentation fault, or don't you check the return value and just used it? In the latter case the question should be why you can not open this file.

Comment: No, `fopen()` doesn't give you a segmentation fault error.  The code that you *didn't* post that uses `f` after `fopen()` failed and you didn't check for errors is what's giving you a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is a notation that is expanded by your shell (e.g. Bash) into your home directory, so if you invoke a program like `vim ~/proj/viagens.txt`, the shell will expand the parameter into `/home/ventura/proj/viagens.txt` *before* the program `vim` ever sees it. `~` is *not* understood by `fopen`, which requires an absolute path path or a path relative to the current working directory.

(As @Osiris and @AndrewHenle point out in their comments, `fopen` doesn't segfault, but it will return null when it can't find the file, which will cause a segfault down the line when you try to use `f` as a file descriptor.)

Comment: Then fopen returns NULL, which is probably the reason of the segmentation fault. You should elaborate on this, since this is the actual question...